# How to implement Personal Access Token(PAT) for Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection for azure Devops

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, tfs

We have powershell script where we are creating New-Object of TfsTeamProjectCollection

```
$collectionData = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection($devops_Url, $TFSCredentials)
```

Windows credentials are passed to create the object:

```
$credentials = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $TfsUser, $TfsPass
$netCred = $credentials.GetNetworkCredential()
$winCred = New-Object 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.WindowsCredential' -ArgumentList $netCred
$TFSCredentials = New-Object 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsClientCredentials' -ArgumentList $winCred
$collectionData = new-object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollection($devops_Url, $TFSCredentials)
```

I need to change the above login method to Personal Access Token (PAT).

any guidence how to do so

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, what have you tried? If it hasn't worked, *how* hasn't it worked? Please provide additional details on what troubleshooting steps you've taken so far.

Comment: Tried Following, no success

1 st:

$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.IssuedToken($PAT)


2nd:
$token = New-Object  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.IssuedToken -ArgumentList $PAT
$credentials = New-Object  VssCredentials(New-Object WindowsCredential(New-Object  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.IssuedTokenCredential($token)))
$connection = New-Object  VssConnection(New-Object  Uri($tfsUrl), $credentials)

3rd:
VssConnectionconnection = new VssConnection(newUri($tfsUrl), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, $PAT))